# Sign-in for Apple using Firebase in Unity on Android throws 'client does not match api key' exception

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to to get apple sign-in with Firebase for Unity working on android.

I've followed their set-up instructions but my situation is a little more complicated than the standard, I don't want to go into details about the set up, but using the code below:

```
FederatedOAuthProviderData providerData = new FederatedOAuthProviderData();
providerData.ProviderId = "apple.com";
var scopes = new List<string>();
scopes.Add("email");
scopes.Add("name");
providerData.Scopes = scopes;
```

whenever I run either

```
 Auth.SignInWithProviderAsync(oAuthProvider)
```

or

```
User.LinkWithProviderAsync(provider)
```

I get the following error:

```
there was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash. [client does not match api key]
```

Can anyone tell me exactly what this error is trying to tell me. I have accounts working for GameCenter, GooglePlay, Google and Facebook but all those use the credential flow and not the new provider one.

Cheers.

Adding more info to clarify the set-up:

There's the default app which has it's own firebase project, this is the one with the linked apps, sha-1 etc... this project provides the google-services.json.

There's an accounts firebase project with no apps associated - this firebase project has been set up to support Sign-in with Apple as well as all the other providers we support and has a link to the service ID as per the instructions.

I use the multiple projects feature in our apps creating an accounts app with

FirebaseApp.Create(accountsAppOptions, "Accounts");

Authentication is done through the Auth of this app.

Once a user successfully authenticates with the accounts auth, I mint a custom token using a cloud function and authenticate with the default app using that.

This works well for GooglePlay, GameCenter, Google, Firebase. But I'm wondering whether this flow is supported by Sign-in with apple as it stands?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely make sure you're [as up to date as possible](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity) with the Firebase Unity SDK. Apple Sign In support is new, so you don't want to miss any potential fixes.

Then, make sure your [SHA-1](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/whats-keytool-why-can-t-it-be-found-and-why-does-firebase-even-want-a-sha-1-a3f568867a7b?source=friends_link&sk=2807ea8db8341a60ca80de582ac7c635) is up to date for development. If you're signing with your debug keystore, that's specific for each dev machine and can be uploaded in addition to your release keystore. Additionally, not everything requires a SHA-1, but Auth is the hotbed of SHA-1 gated features so it wouldn't be surprising if this was the missing piece of configuration.

Last, make sure you've followed all the setup steps. In particular, if you look at [Configure Sign In with Apple](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/apple#configure-sign-in-with-apple), you'll see a link to the [Android Configure Sign In with Apple](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/apple#configure-sign-in-with-apple) page that includes a good bit of configuration that you have to do to get everything operational. Also make sure you've followed all the steps to Enable [Apple as a sign-in provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/apple#enable-apple-as-a-sign-in-provider). This key may not have been fully setup.

I hope this all helps, and I'd love to hear which part of this (if any) solves the issue to see if the docs could be shored up a bit!

--Patrick

Comment: HI Patrick, thanks for all the info. I've gone through and believe I have set-up everything properly. But the whole setup of our accounts is not standard. I've added more information to the the question above if you'd be good enough to take a look.

Comment: It would be interesting to know _if_ it works in your main app (DefaultInstance) but doesn't in your secondary app. Apple Sign-In is very new, and sometimes assumptions are made about the Firebase singleton deeper in the SDK. If you can narrow it down to the secondary Firebase instance, you'd want to file a bug report: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues

Comment: I also don't know the exact details of how the sha-1 is working, but you might have to put an app in the secondary firebase account with a sha-1 for Apple auth to work. Which would create a duplicate sha-1 exception (you can't have the same sha-1 and package id in two different Firebase projects).

Comment: yeah I actually tried that and got exactly that exception. I'm going to try to get it working inside the default app as a test.

Comment: So I've been asking around, and it sounds like auth tokens are intentionally scoped to a project. From how you've described your setup, this may be intended behaviour for security purposes.